# webhost4life make root domain point to www, httpd.ini

Tags: dns, redirect, apache, web-hosting

In webhost4life, anyone know how I can redirect the user when the they hit the root domain, i.e. **gogo.com** redirect to **www.gogo.com**

Thanks

-Mantisimo

I've found a configuration file in the root called httpd.ini

This contains the followig

```
[ISAPI_Rewrite]

### subdomain redirect v2 ###
RewriteCond Host: ?gogo\.com
RewriteCond URL ^gogo.com/(.*)
RewriteCond METHOD GET
RewriteRule .? www.gogo.com/(.*) /$1 [I,R]
RewriteCond Host: (?:.+\.)?gogo\.com
RewriteCond METHOD POST
RewriteRule ^/gogo.com/(.*) /$1 [I]
RewriteCond Host: (?:.+\.)?gogo\.com
RewriteRule (.*) /gogo.com/$1 [I,L]
```

Can someone explain how I can change this? I've found some code on mod_rewrite but this is iis. I dont have a great understadning of regular exressions so this is a bit of a black art to me

Can any help?

Thanks

Comment: +1 I also get into w4l stuff and this is going my library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! :)

```
# Move anything from non- www.example.com -> www.example.com
# e.g. example.com -> www.example.com
RewriteCond %HTTPS off
RewriteCond Host: (?!^www.example.com)(.+)
RewriteRule /(.*) http\://www.example.com/$2 [I,RP]
```

I just added this above replacing the domain :)

http://www.seoconsultants.com/windows/isapi/rules/

Comment: good work. thanks for giving me the credit for the answer, but maybe you should mark yours the correct one if it's still possible to change that.

Comment: Thanks, sorry just noticed your message. I've updated this as the correct answer. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

technically you're not talking about the domain but rather the webserver's response to a request. it can be done any number of ways, but check out Apache's mod_rewrite.

See the section "Canonical Hostnames" at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Comment: Thanks for the pointer in the right direction... I tried adding the .htaccess file and making guestimated changes to redirect. It caused a server error. I then realised there is another redirect file for iis, the httpd.ini file which does the same thing. Is the script syntax identical? I've added the code above which is included in my current project. I can change it easily because it breaks the online site? I dont suppose you can give me some pointer? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the old WebHost4Life interface, simply click on "Set Redirection" and point gogo.com to www.gogo.com

Comment: Hi, Thanks, I've looking the webhost4life interface, unfortunately i'm on the new interface. I've located in the IIS Administration console there is a Url Redirects option but it only redirects the folder to a domain. So it's no good. I need an option to specify gogo.com > www.gogo.com.